# how to set encoding when using readAsText in ngCordova file plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, csv, encoding, ngcordova

I'm trying to read the contents from a CSV file using readAsText ngCordova plugins.

I can do it only when the encoding of file is `unicode`, but most CSV files are `Shift-JIS`. And I can read nothing from the file when it is `Shift-JIS`

My code likes below:

```
$cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.documentsDirectory + CSVS_DIR, fileName).then(
    function (success) {
        console.log("reading csv");
        console.log("csv content: " + success); 
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // error
    });
```

Is there any one know how to deal with it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole day on this issue, I finally find out the answer.

Unfortunately, the answer is NO. We cannot achieve it by using `readAsText`.

According to the [docs of ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/), the API do not support the encoding parameter in `readAsText` function as the cordova-file-plugin has.

Besides, after I read the [document of codova-file-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#ios-quirks), I realized that  the `readAsText` function in Cordova-file-plugin does not support the encoding parameter when it runs in ios.

**SOLUTION**

As `readAsText` cannot do this, I tried the other functions provided in ngCordova. And I found `readAsBinaryString`. This function seems just read the content of file no matter what the encoding it is. So, I can read the content and encode it into Unicode by [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js).

codes:

```
$cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString(cordova.file.documentsDirectory + CSVS_DIR, fileName).then(
    function (success) {
        console.log("reading csv");
        console.log("csv content: " + success);
        var detected = Encoding.detect(success);
        success = Encoding.convert(success, {
            to: 'UNICODE', // to_encoding
            from: detected // from_encoding
        });

        console.log("csv content: " + success);         
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // error    
    });
```

Hope my solution can help.